# KiCAD 5 ‒ Is ist possible for a footprint to have multiple courtyards?

Tags: kicad, footprint, drc

One of the components I am using is really a daughterboard that plugs into two rows of pin headers. Under the daughterboards, between the pin headers, there is space for a additional components. I have therefor designed the footprint for the daughterboard with two courtyards, one for each row of pin headers:

[image: module footprint with two courtyards]

However, this fails in DRC, with KiCAD (in the German translation) saying that the courtyard is "not a closed contour":

[image]

Is there a way to have multiple courtyards in a single component that passes DRC, or should I delete the courtyards altogether?

Comment: I can't think of any reason that multiple courtyards would not be allowed. But the phrase *"not a closed contour"* suggests that perhaps one or both of your shapes has endpoints that don't meet precisely. Zoom in on them and verify -- in particular, I see a slightly tilted line on the upper right that looks suspicious.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @DaveTweed, you're right. It was the bottom right corner. The drawn lines overlapped to form a closed contour, but their centers did not. Fixed it, now it works.